Windows Forms with C#/C++-CLI: Error while declaring std::vector<System::Decimal>
While I can declare the following:
private: 
   std::vector<System::Int32>* test = new std::vector<System::Int32>;

I get an error while declare the following:
private: 
   std::vector<System::Decimal>* test = new std::vector<System::Decimal>;

1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector(874,39): error C3699: '&&': cannot use this indirection on type '_Ty'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector(874,39): error C3699:         with
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector(874,39): error C3699:         [
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector(874,39): error C3699:             _Ty=System::Decimal
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector(874,39): error C3699:         ]

Could anyone please help?
Thanks in advance

You can't use this type.  The C++/CLI compiler treats System::Int32 as an alias for an unmanaged int, but there is no equivalent unmanaged type for System::Decimal.  Consider List<Decimal>^.  And keep in mind that you are not programming in C#, the language is called C++/CLI.

Thank you my friend! Indeed, I'm fully confused. I have only programmed in C and C++ for 6 years. And now I need to built a UI for a C++ program I have created. And I'm just walking blindly, from youtube etc on how to create a UI. I don't know C#, CLI etc. Of course I see similarities but things like the one I mentioned I don't get them. And I'm not programmer. I'm structural engineer.

If you want a modern GUI written in and for C++, use WinUI3 (Windows App SDK). You can work with modern C++ with no issues!

Thank you! I will check. But I think I can't go back now. The UI has gone far enough to return to scratch. But thank you for the advice!

System::Decimal is a C++/CLI (i.e. .NET) type and it cannot be put in a std::vector which is a native C++ class.
This is the meaning of the error message you get (errors related the templates in C++ tend to be rather cryptic).
Note that in general it is not a good idea to mix .NET types and native C++ ones.
In the case of std::vector<System::Int32> you "get away" with the mix, because System::Int32 is just an alias for a native int.
But I would suggest as a general rule to avoid such a mix.
Instead of using std::vector in a .NET environment, you can use System::Collections::Generic::List which has some resemblance to it (continous memory, random access etc.).
For System::Decimal you can use:
System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Decimal> ^ test = 
                  gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Decimal>();

Note that C++/CLI (i.e. .NET) reference types are allocated with gcnew (which is equivalent to the C# new), not with the native C++ new.
A side note:
Whenever you do need to use a native std::vector is recommended to use it directly, and not via a pointer, e.g.:
std::vector<int> v;

